# How do I put jQuery code in an external file in WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am relatively new to Javascript/jQuery so please bear with me.

I'm designing a custom WordPress theme and I have been using jQuery to make some changes to the main navigation menu that is generated in my header file (header.php). I have been adding code like this inside the head tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('nav').mouseover(function() {
        // my mousecode here...
      }); // end mouseover
    }); // end ready
  </script>
```

My question is simple really. My scripts have gotten so long that I want to move them to their own file (perhaps nav-mouse-events.js) and call them from within header.php. How do I do this? Is it as simple as putting the code inbetween the second script tags into a file named nav-mouse-events.js and then adding this to the head tag?

```
<script src="nav-mouse-events.js"></script>
```

Or do I need to do something more complicated? Do I need to call jQuery from the new external file or header.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would put the scripts in a `.js` file and use `wp_enqueue_script` in `functions.php` to include them the proper way.

From the [wordpress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script):

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but isnt it best practice to first `wp_register_script` and then `wp_enqueue_script`. I understand your way is also valid...

Comment: @DavidChase I actually see no need for registering the script first. I could be wrong though so don't quote me on that :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url ');?>/nav-mouse-events.js"></script>
```

and save `nav-mouse-events.js` file with code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('nav').mouseover(function() {
        // my mousecode here...
      }); // end mouseover
    }); // end ready
```

in your **template folder**.